# Is there a difference between this two ways of importing in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have seen this line of code before in React
`import {Something} from "Somethingelse"` then I've also seen this one `import Something from "Somethingelse"` what's the difference between the two and when and why would I use either? and also is it a good idea to skip javascript and learn react directly if you are already pretty familiar with another language like Java for example?

Comment: This isn't a React issue. [This to do with named/default exports](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910). And React is a _JS library_. If you don't understand JS you will struggle with it.

Comment: The reason you had this question in the first place is because you skiped JavaScript and looked at React. Conclusion: learn JS at its core then move to React.

Comment: hey @dhruwlalan sorry I must have phrased my question wrong. I didn't skip javascript completely. I know the basics but I don't feel confident going into react yet. I know a lot of java and I was wondering if that may or may not give me an upper hand to kind of jump over advanced javascript. you get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a difference between this two ways of importing any component in react.

1. First way of importing

   ```
   import Something from "Somethingelse"
   ```

   you can use this when you are exporting any function as default like below.

   ```
   export default Somethingelse
   ```
2. Second way of importing

   ```
   import {Something} from "Somethingelse"
   ```

   You can use the above syntax when you have exported any function as const like below.

   ```
   export const Somethingelse
   ```

And for your second question.

I would recommend to at least learn basics of the JavaScript before jumping into React even if you know language like Java, Because JavaScript is quite different from Java.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is related to how the module (the functions inside it) is exported. If we write `export default someFunc` then we can import it using `import someFunc from someFile`. But if instead we write `export {someFunc}` then we have to import it using `import {someFunc} from someFile`.

You should understand the fundamentals of JS, especially **Prototypal inheritance**. JS OOPS are somewhat different from OOPS of Java, so understanding them will definitely help, because `props` in ReactJS works on the concept of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Importing via the ways you mentioned is dependent on exporting these files. To be accurate, when we use

`export const default Something`

we use
`import Something from "Somethingelse"`

,
and when we use

`export const Something`

we use
`import {Something} from "Somethingelse"`

. Here is the hint, in the second case we can use `import {Anything as Something} from "Somethingelse"`(and can use as `Anything` in your project!)

2. Regarding learning javascript before react, I consider, you should as js is the core of React or any js framework/library. But you can also skip (even though you cannot skip javascript base) advanced js if you think you should learn something soon